# converting object to int of a large dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

how can I convert a large dataframe of a column from object to int.

Dataframe :

```
user              
1101110110100        
1111222555555
1112223365556
1113656560005
asaseee"
tdyhhdy"

dtype: object
```

expected:

```
user
1101110110100
1111222555555
1112223365556
1113656560005

dtype: int64
```

I have used the below codes.

```
df['user'].astype(int)
df['user'].astype(str).astpe(int)
```

Comment: It seems dupe, do you try `df['user'] = df['user'].astype(int)` ?

Comment: yes i tried ... s hows me the below error. `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Comment: using numpy ,can you try df['user'] = df['user'].astype(np.int64)?

Comment: What is the largest integer value (`df['user'].max()`)? If it is larger than 9223372036854775807 (`np.iinfo(np.int64).max`), then life becomes more complicated...

Comment: sorry all, I have a alphabetic string in here, so i was not able to convert it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try cast to `int64`:

```
df['user'] = df['user'].astype(np.int64)
```

Or:

```
df['user'] = df['user'].astype('int64')
```

---

```
print (df['user'])
0    1101110110100
1    1111222555555
2    1112223365556
3    1113656560005
Name: user, dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

```
#convert not parseable values to NaNs
df['user'] = pd.to_numeric(df['user'], errors='coerce')
#remove rows with NaNs
df = df.dropna('user')
df['user'] = df['user'].astype(np.int64)
```

Or:

```
df['user'] = pd.to_numeric(df['user'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['user'] = df['user'].astype(np.int64)
```

Comment: @pylearner - Please check my edit. Also for bad values is necessary remove all rows? Else get `NaN`s and convert to int create very weird values.

Comment: There are 2 possible ways - remove rows or replace nan to int.

Comment: `df['user'] = pd.to_numeric(df['user'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)' this is converting my values to float, `1.113+14`

Comment: Sorry, I dont add second row to edit. Now it should working.

Comment: Awesome, I got it. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

you can cast into big int using numpy

```
import numpy as np
df['user'] = df['user'].astype(np.int64)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['user'] = pd.to_numeric(df['user'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

This is working fine.. I have tried for one problem which I have faced
it's convert object into float